# populate PictureBox with Images using Foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox, imagelist

In my project I have collection of PictureBoxes and a filled ImageList. I want to populate each pictureBox with the each Image in ImageList using `foreach` Loop. I know how to do using For loop but I dont know how to do it using foreach loop. I am asking this just for knowledge purpose. I think this can be achieved using Linq inside foreach loop but I am a beginner so I have no Idea how to do it.

I tried the below code in for loop:

```
        for (intimgcount = 0; intimgcount < intMaxPics; intimgcount++)
        {                
            pbxCollection[intimgcount].Image = imglst.Images[intimgcount];          
        }
```

the code which  I want to use in `foreach` loop is:

```
        var pbxCollection = new List<PictureBox>();  //PictureBox collection
```

EDIT:  How to set the positions of Picture Box collection in the form?

I tried:

```
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var pbx in pbxCollection)
        {
            pbx.Image = imglst.Images[i++];
            //set location:
            pbx.Width = 100;
            pbx.Height = 100;
            pbx.Location = new Point(0, pbx.Height * i);
            //add to form:
            this.Controls.Add(pbx);
        }
```

Comment: If you do need an "i" you're probably better of to use a for loop.

Comment: @Carra no I dont need "i" (if it is not necessary), it was just edit after seeing the answers. I just need an answer in foreach loop which I think I got but I dont know how to set the positions of the PictureBox in the form. for example --> 10 pictureBoxes , 5 top and 5 bottom.

Comment: Use a tablelayout and add your pictureboxes to its controls.

Comment: @Carra I need to do this dynamically (everything). which I dont know. Anyway I found the trick. The trick is first design your form with required controls and refer program.cs :)

Comment: Glad to see it works. You can add controls to the tablelayout through code, just add it to its controls. And it's easier if you want to split them in two or more columns :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
var pbxCollection = new List<PictureBox>();
foreach (Image img in imglst.Images)
{ 
     PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
     pb.Image = img;
     pbxCollection.Add(pb); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. VS is showing red scribbles to `pbxCollection.Add(img);` and the pbxCollection is not list of image collections.

Comment: Hey sorry, maybe it is working. I havent set the positions to the picture box on the form (just declared). do you know how to set them.

Comment: You will have to change the position for each picturebox you can set it by pb.Left = 10; pb.Top = 10;

Comment: You will also need to set size of picture box like pb.Width = 50;           pb.Height = 50;

Comment: @Adil still not loading. Please see my edit. Sorry for late response having seminar.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to increment index of collection:

```
var i = 0;
foreach (var pbx in pbxCollection)
{
    pbx.Image = imglst.Images[i++];
    //set location:
    pbx.Location = new Point(0, pbx.Image.Height * i);
    //add to form:
    this.Controls.Add(pbx);
}
```

Comment: Hey sorry, maybe it is working. I havent set the positions to the picture box on the form (just declared). do you know how to set them.

Comment: still not loading. Please see my edit. Sorry for late response having seminar.